# Align a TextView next to each other - Android

Tags: android, textview, width

I have 2 Text View in a Layout. 
The first one is on the left and the second on the right 
The first one should have a width of 80%
and the second should have a width of 20%

How can i make it ?

And i can't figure out which layout to choose : Linear Layout or Relative Layout

Thanks!

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` using weight to define view what you are asking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can user Linear layout with weight property 80 and 20

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:text="yes"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="80"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="No"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weightSum property of LinearLayout and layout_weight of each child views. simply :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weight_sum="100">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout. It provides facility to specify width or height in percentage in the form of layout_weight and weightSum attributes.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="first text view"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="second text view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Should work. Here weight sum is 10 and divided into weight 8 and 2 , that means in 80% and 20% . Will solve your problem.